# Conditionally render component depending on localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to rerender component when localStorage changes by changing state. The problem is if I set state inside `useEffect` hook page doesn't rerender. If I put it outside `useEffect` I get infinite loop. I'm sure localStorage changes because I'm getting wanted results when refreshing page. Here is my code snippet:

```
function Header(props) {

    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({loggedIn : false})


    useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('auth')) {
            setAuth(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth')))
        }
    },[])


    const logOut = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('auth');
        setAuth({loggedIn : false});
    }

    let listContainer = (
        <div className={styles.LinkContainer}>
        <div className={styles.NavigationLink} onClick={props.openLoginModal}>Login</div>
        <div className={styles.NavigationLink} onClick={props.openRegistrationModal}>Register</div>
    </div>
    )
    if (auth.loggedIn) {
        listContainer = (
        <div className={styles.LinkContainer}>
            <div className={styles.NavigationLink}>Weekly plan</div>
            <div className={styles.NavigationLink}>Shopping list</div>
            <div className={styles.NavigationLink}>Options</div>
            <div className={styles.NavigationLink} onClick={logOut}>Logout</div>
        </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.Container}>
            <img src="/logo.png"
                alt="HiFoodelity logo"
                className={styles.LogoImage} />
            {listContainer}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `setAuth(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth')))` will cause the component to rerender. Are you saying this doesn't happen?

Comment: your using useEffect with [] array, it should render only once , what you mean by infinite loop? ,

Comment: Unfortunately I'm sure. Header stays the same, it changes only when I refresh page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing [] from useEffect hook which executes only on page load, so instead of this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('auth')) {
        setAuth(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth')))
    }
},[])
```

I wrote it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('auth') && auth.loggedIn === false) {
        setAuth(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth')))
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What u want to do, because on every time component will render useEffect() will be call, and u change the state which will cause rerender the component, so that your component will be under infinite rendering state.